# Como percorrer todos os controles de uma janela em WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, controles

Existe alguma forma de eu percorrer todos os controles de uma janela e desabilitá-los? Por exemplo, fazer um `foreach` que desabilite um por um dos controles. Algo como abaixo, só que para WPF, e não WinForms.

```
private void HabilitarControles(bool habilita)
    {
        foreach (Control c in Controls)
        {
            c.Enabled = habilita;
            foreach (Control con in c.Controls.OfType<Control>())
                con.Enabled = habilita;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não tem porque fazer isto um por um. Provavelmente você coloca eles dentro de um `Panel` (se não faz, deveria), desabilite apenas o `Panel`. Todos serão desabilitados.

Se ainda insistir nisso é fazer o que você já sabe fazer:

```
private void HabilitarControles(bool habilita) => foreach (var c in this.Controls) c.Enabled = habilita;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WPF/EnableControls.cs).

Se deseja alguma outra sofisticação é só adaptar isto. Não há outros requisitos na pergunta.

Comment: Os meus controles estão todos em uma grid. Se tentar utilizar este método, me retorna o erro: "The name 'Controls' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Mudei e acho que vai resolver. Quando é assim, você tem que colocar na pergunta. Não temos como adivinhar os problemas que está tendo. Mas de qualquer forma, desabilite o `GridPanel`, é mais fácil.

Comment: Realmente, desabilitar a Grid é melhor. Porém , mesmo usando o 'this' no código, ele não reconhece o Controls.

Comment: Sem um contexto maior fica difícil ajudar.